# How can I make text from right to left animation with loop with out cut it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I am saying about the cut, I am trying to do something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/44GvS.gif

```css
.auto-scrolling-casing-category-main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.font-awesome-Caregory {
  margin-right: 45px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.font-awesome-Caregory p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.image-Category {
  margin-right: 45px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-Category p {
  padding-top: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <div id="auto-scrolling-maind" class="auto-scrolling-casing-category-main d-flex">
    <div class="font-awesome-Caregory">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x center-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p> text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-Category">
      <img src="images/picture_1.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" alt="">
      <p class=""> text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="font-awesome-Caregory">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x center-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-Category text-center">
      <img src="images/picture_1.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" alt="">
      <p class="">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="font-awesome-Caregory">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x center-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-Category">
      <img src="images/picture_1.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" alt="">
      <p class="">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="font-awesome-Caregory">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x center-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-Category text-center">
      <img src="images/picture_1.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" alt="">
      <p class="">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="font-awesome-Caregory">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x center-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-Category">
      <img src="images/picture_1.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" alt="">
      <p class="">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="font-awesome-Caregory">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x center-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-Category">
      <img src="images/picture_1.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" alt="">
      <p class="">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="font-awesome-Caregory">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x center-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-Category">
      <img src="images/picture_1.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" alt="">
      <p class="">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="font-awesome-Caregory">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x center-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-Category">
      <img src="images/picture_1.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" alt="">
      <p class="">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="font-awesome-Caregory">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x center-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-Category">
      <img src="images/picture_1.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" alt="">
      <p class="">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="font-awesome-Caregory">
      <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x center-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-Category">
      <img src="images/picture_1.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" alt="">
      <p class="">text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for answers! I really need that help

Comment: Could you add some more detail about what you're trying to do - it's really not clear.

Comment: Hey , thanks you for your answer , i am trying to make animation that will see all the div inside the(auto-scrolling-maind , the animation will go from right to left and when he got the end he will repeat it,i am trying to do endless loop animation , thats mean when he got to the end of the divs he will countinu to show divs , but will not pause it and instantly will go to the start and do it again , he will just continue to show the first divs , its like the gif i posted here , when he finish is animation he instatly will come back from other side .

Comment: Sorry for my bad english , and if you didnt underatand yet tell me pls , i will try to explain me more clearly,its really important for me .